# Ubuntu 14.04: "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?" after Docker update

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

On a Ubuntu 14.04 server instance I uninstalled the previous Docker version and installed `docker-ce`.

Now, when I'm trying to issue for example `docker ps`, I get

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Running `sudo docker ps` does not fix it.
Restarting the Server using `sudo service docker restart` neither does fix it.
Current user is already in `docker` group.

Comment: Please add a result of `$ service docker status` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
/var/log/upstart/docker.log
```

Did contain this entry:

```
Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: /var/lib/docker contains several valid graphdrivers: devicemapper, aufs; Please cleanup or explicitly choose storage driver (-s <DRIVER>)
```

I deleted `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper` and everything went back to normal.